# Migrate monolith to microservices without touching database

Tags: architecture, containers, microservices

We have a big monolithic application with a huge oracle db. We want to move the application to a microservices architecture using containers without doing so much at database level. We are going to change the db later on.

What is the best approach to isolate services and what should we do to make it less painful when we change database in the next phase?

Would it not be a problem at db level when you have multiple processes (one for each service)?

Comment: Have you done an indepth snap analysis of your app? Take a look at this [link](http://cloud.rohitkelapure.com/2016/10/snap-analysis-of-applications.html)

Answer (score 3):

Refactoring the processing aspect of your application without refactoring the data it uses could potentially lead of problems, one of them being an ever increasing technical debt load. Since you're getting a lot of consistency "free" with your large RDBMS, do you plan on also postponing the implementation of all the event-based asynchronous notifications and updates you'll need to add to support each service? If these endpoints haven't even been identified, it seems you'll be refactoring more than your database after the initial completion of your microservices. Apart from database-structure independent core business logic, expect another iteration of development of these microservices once you break up your database.

Yes you may have problems "at db level when you have multiple processes". The problem being that right now in your monolith you likely have transactions that span tables that belong to (or serve) more than one business domain - domains that will likely be destined to reside in separate microservices.

I would suggest a more holistic approach where you refactor your database and monolith into microservices incrementally together. Choose an easy to isolate part of your monolith and start with that.  It could comprise a small API of a couple REST endpoints, and separate its data to its own tables. For REST GETS, use whatever method you like to move data from your monolith DB to these tables to keep them synchronized. For persistence methods, use an event queue and simple service to update the monolith data from your microservice datastore. Then move on to the next service. As you continue, you can begin to decommission services and any other mechanisms you used to maintain data consistency between your microservice schemas and your monolith database schema.  Without an unknown amount of technical debt being accumulated, it might even be possible to better predict your project outcome after your first few user stories are implemented!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle database is injected in a PCF foundation. You can do that as follows..

- CUPS service
- Service Broker

Once a the db is injected into the pcf, then you can create service instance and bind it to your apps.

The changes will be to your app. You will have to refactor it, to get the db details from the cloud environment. Rest of the interaction can remain same.

As to converting your monolithic app to microservices, there are different approaches. When to use which are on case-by-case basis and an organization's ability and willingness for accepting change.

A common one is called "Strangulation Pattern". This approach allows you to incrementally migrate a monolith to microservices. In this approach, you extract high value features, and convert them to microservices. The old monolith then either ignores those features, or is refactored to call these microservices.

There are other considerations that must be addressed. They include session handling, logging to files etc.

Hope this helps!